# UvSqares Add-on doesn´t work/ get installed

Tags: add-on

https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares/blob/master/uv_squares.py

This add-on was recommended to me, but I  see no zip-file.The other files seem to be installed; there appears a message about the location.
[image: add-on]

Anyway, the extra section in the N panel keeps missing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Go back a couple of directories to https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares, and from the *Code* menu select *Download Zip*

[image: Code Menu showing Download Zip option]

That will download `UvSquares-master.zip`.

Go to preferences -> Add-ons, select *install* and then select that file.  Once it's installed it'll show up and you can enable it.

Comment: Yes thanks, that´s it. Go to file was a bit misleading. Code is the right way.